# Pasar una variable de Ajax a una variable Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

Hola Chicos soy nuevo trabajando con ajax, asi que se me ha presentado el problema de que quiero usar la variable de Ajax al cual le he asignado el valor del response para después trabajarlo de manera publica.

```
function fixCode(){
        var lastID = '';
        $.ajax({
            url:"lastID.php",
            type: "GET",
            success: function(response){
            lastID = response;
            }
            
        })
        return lastID
    }
    fixCode();
    console.log(lastID);
```

Pero al inspeccionar me sale que no está definida.

Comment: Las llamadas a Ajax son asíncronas, por lo tanto no puedes hacer asignaciones en cascada porque puede que la llamada Ajax no haya terminado y asignado el valor cuando intentes usarlo. Es un tema amplio en Javascript que ha venido a resolverse con lo que se conoce como *Promesas* (Promise en inglés). De una forma simple, si quieres usar la respuesta de Ajax en otra función, tendrás que llamar esa función desde el `suiccess` de Ajax y pasarle la respuesta... ([ver ejemplo aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44154594/5587982)) o simplemente, usar los datos dentro del mismo `success`...

Comment: En la respuesta aceptada de la pregunta referida en mi primer comentario encontrarás explicado con detalle todo el asunto de las Promesas con relación a Ajax. Conviene leerla detenidamente y modernizar tu código (las últimas versiones de Ajax implementan cierto tipo de Promesas para Ajax, mediante `done, fail, complete`, etc. Conviene que las uses, sustituyendo a `success` que es obsoleto desde jQuery 3.

Comment: Sumado a que la variable esta dentro del bloque de la fx, y al momento de llamar a `fixCode()` no se lo estas asignando a ninguna variable

Answer (score 1):

Como ya mencionaron en los comentarios, las llamadas de AJAX son asíncronas por defecto. Esto significa que, en tu código, la línea

`console.log(lastID);`

se corre antes que la función de `success`, pues el AJAX no espera a que se complete su proceso antes de continuar. Por esta razón, la variable `lastID` todavía tiene valor de string vacío cuando haces el `console.log`.

Para hacer que la llamada sea síncrona, debes especificarlo colocando la propiedad `async` falsa:

```
function fixCode() {
    var lastID = '';
    $.ajax({
        url : "lastID.php",
        type : "GET",
        async : false,
        success : function(response) {
            lastID = response;
        }   
    });
    return lastID;
}

fixCode();
console.log(lastID);
```

Otra cosa que puedes hacer es utilizar `async-await` para dejarle saber al AJAX que tu función debe devolver una promesa y esperar a que el AJAX concluya:

```
async function fixCode() {
    var lastID = '';
    await $.ajax({
        url : "lastID.php",
        type : "GET",
        success : function(response) {
            lastID = response;
        }   
    });
    return lastID;
}

fixCode();
console.log(lastID);
```

Comment: Se esta usando de manera incorrecta `await` y ademas esto no resuelve el problema del `OP`, (seguiria teniendo el mismo problema), realmente eso de declarar una variable global dentro del cuerpo de donde ejecutas el ajax no necesariamente hace que el contenido de la variable sea asignado al mismo tiempo, por lo tanto realmente no hay ningun cambio en lo que el OP tiene como problema, hay que leer mas sobre las promesas, en este caso yo consideraria que lo mejor seria usar promises.

Comment: Saludos Riven. Con todo respeto, lo he utililzado en mi propio código tal como lo muestro y me funciona a la perfección.

Comment: Saludos, La primera quiza funcione por hacer el ajax sincrono cosa que no es recomendable, la segunda definitivamente no funcionaria, el `await` no puede ser usado de esa manera. sin mencionar que no hace las vecez de un return y no le estas asignando nada al resultado del `await`, por lo tanto el await esta realizando un proceso que se pierde.

Comment: De todas maneras retirare mi voto negativo porque al ver la primera parte veo que si que podria funcionar, pero te recomiendaria arreglar la segunda parte para que no confundas al OP, pues la segunda definitivamente no funcionaria. porfavor edita la respuesta para poder quitar mi voto ;3

Comment: No sé qué decirte. Lo acabo de verificar de nuevo y sí, me funciona. Si quito el await, la variable se devuelve vacía; si lo dejo, la variable se devuelve con el valor que se le coloca en success.

Comment: Caí en cuenta que  olvidé incluir el ```async``` antes de declarar la función, lo cual efectivamente hace que devuelva una promesa. Con esta modificación es tal como lo he usado y me funciona.

Comment: exacto, ese era el error, ahora voto arriba, porque ambas partes ahora funcionarian correctamente.

Comment: gracias por tu paciencia jajaja